# A problem with a list-arrow UITableView Swift UIKit

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a problem with the lists arrow. The arrows point to the right when the lists are closed. When we open respectively up. But if you scroll the page to the bottom and return to the beginning, the arrows will already be to the right in different directions. Any ideas why?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because UITableView reuses TableViewCell, it regenerates them to the default when you scroll again! so you need to save the state in your Model class and reassign the previous state